# React Native + Parse.com Push Notifications on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, push, react-native

Couldn't find any documentation on how to handle push notifications coming from Parse on React Native for Android.
I am able to receive the notification after integrating the SDK, but couldn't go from there in order to handle the notification inside the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

No Problem.
This is php code.

```
$data = array("alert" => 'Hello, this í' );
                  ParsePush::send(array(
                      "channels" => ["channels"],
                      "data" => $data,
                      "post_id" => '1234',
                  ));
```

And this is Android code.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
String postID = json.getString("post_id");
if (postID != null) {
    Intent parseIntent = new Intent(this, MatchActivity.class);
    parseIntent.putExtra("postID", postID);
    startActivity(parseIntent);
```

}
In android code. You can get parametter post_id from php. Sorry English verry bad

Comment: Hi, I was on vacation so couldn't respond.
I meant that I want to control what to do with the notification using JS - react native.
Currently all i'm able to do is to see the notification - but I want that on click it would go to the right article, by executing a function declared on the react native app itself.
Something like here:
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
But for Parse.